# Pushing new Laravel project, PhpStorm, GitHub

Tags: laravel, git, github, phpstorm

I have created new "fresh" Laravel project in PhpStorm and I am able to add it to the remote GitHub repo. The only issue is that it shows all previous commits for this project.

Is there a way to remove those commits form the history so that I can start working with "clean" commit history?

[image: all original commits]

Comment: You wouldn't usually clone the Laravel repo directly, instead, you should use the (project) package available at packagist.org. This can either be done with the `laravel new` command or using `composer create-project`

Comment: next time follow @Jazerix comment to prevent this from happening. You can however fix this by removing the .git folder and `git init` (and clean out your remote repo)